# The method reduce(Task, BinaryOperator<Task>) in the type Stream<Task> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, hashmap

I am keep getting this error: Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(Task, Task). Please tell how can I solve this issue?

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery()
                .processInstanceId(instanceId)
                .list()
                .stream()
                .reduce(new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>(), (taskData, task, t3) -> {
                    taskData.putIfAbsent(task.getId(), taskService.getVariables(task.getId())); 
                     return taskData;
                })
                .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What type is the function you are passing? How many parameters does its `apply` method take? How many are you passing to it?

Comment: the lambda function need to take two parameters, both need to be `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` and it need to return `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Stream::collect(Collectors.toMap)` with a merge function is more appropriate here than [`Stream::reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery()
                .processInstanceId(instanceId)
                .list()    // List<Task>
                .stream()  // Stream<Task>
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Task::getId  // String key = task.getId()
                    task -> taskService.getVariables(task.getId()) // Map<String, Object>
                    (m1, m2) -> {m1.putAll(m2); return m1; }
                ));
```